# Why do we use upcasting in case of abstract classes?

Tags: java

```
abstract class Bike{
  abstract void run();
}

class Honda extends Bike{
  void run(){
    System.out.print("running");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Bike obj=new Honda(); //Upcasting
    obj.run();
  }
}
```

We could have get the same result using

```
Honda obj=new Honda();
obj.run();
```

why use upcasting? If we can get the same results?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: I get it , this is polymorphism, but again why to ise it here??

Comment: Because it confers flexibility, and maintains a good habit.